# How do I automatically add a slug to my url in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, express, url

I'm having templating issues.

I'm working on an online store and I'm using my json file, which has all the details about a product, to generate cards for each product.
Because I have a lot of products, creating a page for each product is out of the question so I also have a template page to show more details on a product.
What I want is that whenever I click on a product card, it takes me to the template product page then replaces the dummy data with the data for the product. I also want to make the url for the template page `/product/product-slug` but when i use this method, I'm unable to change the dummy data.

I eventually found a way to change the dummy data but the only way I could do it was by using the query id to find the data so the url looks like `/product?id=productId` instead and I really don't know how to work around it. I can't leave it like this because as I said before, I have a lot of products.

Here's my js code

```
const fs = require('fs')
const url = require('url')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const replaceTemplate = (temp, product) =>{
    let output = temp.replace(/{%NAME%}/g, product.name);
    output = output.replace(/{%ID%}/g, product.id);
    output = output.replace(/{%FIRST%}/g, product.image.primary);
    output = output.replace(/{%SECOND%}/g, product.image.secondary);
    output = output.replace(/{%SLUG%}/g, product.slug);
    output = output.replace(/{%PRICE%}/g, product.price);
    output = output.replace(/{%M1NAME%}/g, product.materials.material1.name);
    // output = output.replace(/{%M2NAME%}/g, product.materials.material2.name);
    output = output.replace(/{%M1IMG%}/g, product.materials.material1.img);
    // output = output.replace(/{%M2IMG%}/g, product.materials.material2.img);

    return output;
}

const earrings = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/views/earrings.html`,'utf-8');
const product = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/templates/product.html`,'utf-8');

const tempCard = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/templates/stud-cards.html`,'utf-8');

const data = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/dev-data/earrings/studs.json`,'utf-8');
const dataObj = JSON.parse(data);

app.get('/product', (req, res) => {
    const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true)
    // // // const prod = url.parse(req.url, `http://${req.headers.host}`)
    // // // const prod = dataObj[]
    // // // const output = replaceTemplate(product, prod);
    // // console.log(req.params.slug)
    // // res.end(product);
    // res.render('product', {pro: req.params.slug});

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    const prod = dataObj[query.id];
    const output = replaceTemplate(product, prod);

    console.log(prod);
    res.end(output);
}); 

app.listen(7664);

console.log('Now the server is running in url: http://127.0.0.1:7664');
```

And this is what my json file looks like

```
[
{
        "id": 0,
        "name":"Amethyst Flat Sphere Studs",
        "image":{
            "primary": "../img/products/earrings/studs/Amethyst Flat Sphere Studs/0_BirthstoneSphereStud_AmethystSphereStuds_February_YG_Hero.jpg",
            "secondary": "../img/products/earrings/studs/Amethyst Flat Sphere Studs/2_BirthstoneSphereStud_AmethystSphereStuds_February_YG_Hero_Stacked_1.jpg"
        },
        "slug":"amethyst-flat-sphere-studs",
        "price":"180.00",
        "materials":{
            "material1":{
                "name": "14k Yellow Gold, Amethyst",
                "img": "../img/products/color/Amethyst.png"
            } 
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name":"Aquamarine Flat Sphere Studs",
        "image":{
            "primary": "../img/products/earrings/studs/Aquamarine Flat Sphere Studs/0_BirthstoneSphereStud_AquamarineSphereStuds_March_YG_Hero.jpg",
            "secondary": "../img/products/earrings/studs/Aquamarine Flat Sphere Studs/1_BirthstoneSphereStud_AquamarineSphereStuds_March_YG_Hero_Stacked_1.jpg"
        },
        "slug":"aquamarine-flat-sphere-studs",
        "price":"200.00",
        "materials":{
            "material1":{
                "name": "14k Yellow Gold, Aquamarine",
                "img": "../img/products/color/Aquamarine.png"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is [req.params][1] which will give you access to the URL parameters.

```js
app.get('/product/:productSlug', (request, response) => {
    // this will give you the product slug
    const productSlug = request.params.productSlug;
```

After you receive the slug you need to find the element from the JSON file with the same slug.

```js
    ​// you have an array in that JSON file so iterate through it 
    // and ​check for slug for each element
    // this is based on your use case not recommended when processing 
    // huge record set

   ​let prod;

   for(let el of dataObj){
       if(el[slug] == productSlug){
           prod = el;
           break;
       }
   }

​   const output = replaceTemplate(product, prod);

   ​console.log(prod);
   ​res.end(output);
}
```

Read more about `params`, `query`, and `body` and determine which way is better for your use case.

​[1]: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#re

Comment: I did that already but the data didn't change

Comment: I have updated the answer, you have an array in dataObj, so you have to iterate through that array and get the element that has the same slug as the requested product.

Comment: I keep getting this error message.

`console.log(prod);


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47`