# How do I automatically add a slug to my url in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url

I'm having templating issues.

I'm working on an online store and I'm using my json file, which has all the details about a product, to generate cards for each product. Because I have a lot of products, creating a page for each product is out of the question so I also have a template page to show more details on a product. What I want is that whenever I click on a product card, it takes me to the template product page then replaces the dummy data with the data for the product. I also want to make the url for the template page /product/product-slug but when i use this method, I'm unable to change the dummy data.

I eventually found a way to change the dummy data but the only way I could do it was by using the query id to find the data so the url looks like /product?id=productId instead and I really don't know how to work around it. I can't leave it like this because as I said before, I have a lot of products.

Here's my js code

```
const fs = require('fs')
const url = require('url')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const replaceTemplate = (temp, product) =>{
    let output = temp.replace(/{%NAME%}/g, product.name);
    output = output.replace(/{%ID%}/g, product.id);
    output = output.replace(/{%FIRST%}/g, product.image.primary);
    output = output.replace(/{%SECOND%}/g, product.image.secondary);
    output = output.replace(/{%SLUG%}/g, product.slug);
    output = output.replace(/{%PRICE%}/g, product.price);
    output = output.replace(/{%M1NAME%}/g, product.materials.material1.name);
    // output = output.replace(/{%M2NAME%}/g, product.materials.material2.name);
    output = output.replace(/{%M1IMG%}/g, product.materials.material1.img);
    // output = output.replace(/{%M2IMG%}/g, product.materials.material2.img);

    return output;
}

const earrings = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/views/earrings.html`,'utf-8');
const product = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/templates/product.html`,'utf-8');

const tempCard = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/templates/stud-cards.html`,'utf-8');

const data = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/dev-data/earrings/studs.json`,'utf-8');
const dataObj = JSON.parse(data);

app.get('/product', (req, res) => {
    const { query, pathname } = url.parse(req.url, true)
    // // // const prod = url.parse(req.url, `http://${req.headers.host}`)
    // // // const prod = dataObj[]
    // // // const output = replaceTemplate(product, prod);
    // // console.log(req.params.slug)
    // // res.end(product);
    // res.render('product', {pro: req.params.slug});

    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-type': 'text/html'});
    const prod = dataObj[query.id];
    const output = replaceTemplate(product, prod);

    console.log(prod);
    res.end(output);
}); 

app.listen(7664);

console.log('Now the server is running in url: http://127.0.0.1:7664');
```

And this is what my json file looks like

```
[
{
        "id": 0,
        "name":"Amethyst Flat Sphere Studs",
        "image":{
            "primary": "../img/products/earrings/studs/Amethyst Flat Sphere Studs/0_BirthstoneSphereStud_AmethystSphereStuds_February_YG_Hero.jpg",
            "secondary": "../img/products/earrings/studs/Amethyst Flat Sphere Studs/2_BirthstoneSphereStud_AmethystSphereStuds_February_YG_Hero_Stacked_1.jpg"
        },
        "slug":"amethyst-flat-sphere-studs",
        "price":"180.00",
        "materials":{
            "material1":{
                "name": "14k Yellow Gold, Amethyst",
                "img": "../img/products/color/Amethyst.png"
            } 
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name":"Aquamarine Flat Sphere Studs",
        "image":{
            "primary": "../img/products/earrings/studs/Aquamarine Flat Sphere Studs/0_BirthstoneSphereStud_AquamarineSphereStuds_March_YG_Hero.jpg",
            "secondary": "../img/products/earrings/studs/Aquamarine Flat Sphere Studs/1_BirthstoneSphereStud_AquamarineSphereStuds_March_YG_Hero_Stacked_1.jpg"
        },
        "slug":"aquamarine-flat-sphere-studs",
        "price":"200.00",
        "materials":{
            "material1":{
                "name": "14k Yellow Gold, Aquamarine",
                "img": "../img/products/color/Aquamarine.png"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70482316/how-do-i-automatically-add-a-slug-to-my-url-in-nodejs

Comment: @skara9 I'm sorry what? That's the same question

Comment: why did you ask it twice?

Comment: @skara9 oh cause I didn't get a reply on the first one